# Unable to set JDK to 13.0.2 - "The NDK path does not belong to a directory"

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I've installed both JDK 16.0.1 and 13.0.2 on my system. Android Studio is currently set to use 16.0.1, but I want to change it to 13.0.2.

I also want to use NDK 21.1.6352462. That property has already been set in local.properties.

When I go to File > Project Structure > SDK location, I try to set JDK location to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home` and I get the pop-up shown below:

```
Cannot Save Settings
The NDK path does not belong to a directory
```

If I leave the JDK path at jdk-16.0.1.jdk, everything is fine.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: The NDK path does not belong to a directory]

Comment: I fixed the issue by reverting back to the version of the JDK that ships with Android Studio, rather than the one I wanted. Leaving the question open just in case anybody knows the answer.